# elementRef.createComponent is not a function

Tags: angular

I am trying to load a spinner component dynamically on click of a button.

Plunker link is here,

http://plnkr.co/edit/UEEQQRzX7RIkSO49rCHu?p=preview

```
let elementRef: ElementRef = this.appRef['_rootComponents'][0].location;

    return this.startInside(elementRef, null);
```

I am getting below error:

> elementRef.createComponent is not a function.

Please suggest!

Comment: The problems seems to be that `this.appRef['_rootComponents'][0].location` doesn't return a `ViewContainerRef` as expected. Can you please add the link to the other question that contains links to similar examples?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've adapted your plunkr and forked it to [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/r1UG1OkjgyWbaKCPMA34?p=preview) but in summary you should do this:

Add a placeholder to the template, then assign it as a `@ViewChild` and pass that to the service. Here's the `app.ts` now:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [SpinnerService],
  template: `
    <div>
      <button type="button" (click)="showSpinner()">Show Spinner</button>
      <div #spinner></div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class App {
  @ViewChild('spinner', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container: ViewContainerRef;    

  constructor(private _spinner: SpinnerService) {}

  showSpinner() {
    this._spinner.start(this.container);
    setTimeout(() => this._spinner.stop(), 5000);
  }
}
```

And finally in the service you can just do this:

```
 public start(placeholder) {
        let elementRef = placeholder;
        return this.startInside(elementRef, null);
    }
```

Comment: @Katana24 I had the same issue and your solution almost worked but the message is printed on the root component not in the `spinner-message-container`, can you give me an idea?

Comment: My bad! My style file wasn't picked up! Thank you :)

Comment: Adding `{ read: ViewContainerRef }` did it for me, thanks!